# Line not visible in line chart when having same value in the domain() - using D3

Tags: javascript, web, svg, d3.js, charts

I am trying to build a line chart using **D3** and I am using [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245).

The problem that I am facing is that when I am passing a dataset that contains the same value in the `linear.domain()` fof the `y` then the line of the line chart gets drawn on top of the **horizontal axis** and as a result is not visible. Also no numbers are printed on the **y axis**.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UVbJ9/1/)  with my code.

The `metrics` variable contains 3 objects, three different timestamps with the same value. On the result panel the line is get drawn on top of **x axis**. If you change one of the three values from 5 to any other number then the line chart gets drawn as normal.

Any ideas on how can I draw the line in the middle of the **y axis** when the `metrics` variable contains values of the same value?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of line

```
      y.domain(d3.extent(metrics, function(d) { return d.close; }));
```

use

```
      y.domain([d3.max(metrics, function(d) { return d.close; }) + 0.01,
                d3.min(metrics, function(d) { return d.close; }) - 0.01]);
```

The thing is, if y scale is just segment of length 0, like [5.0, 5.0] (or any other number other that 5.0), d3 is totally confused, and refuses to display anything on y axis, and places 5.0 right at origin.

With new code: the following is obtained for the same case:

[image]]

Here is also [link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J9fAv/).